# React Native Listview data does not refresh when state changed

Tags: android, reactjs, listview, react-native, mobile

I know there are 1000 of similar questions like this but even when trying out different examples I can't get this to work, apologies in advance.

When I pull to refresh my data the request is sent and the new response is received (As verified per my logs).  However, this data is not reflected in the list itself.  I understand the listview is clever enough to refresh the data when there is a change to the datasource but it doesn't seem to be happening here.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    const dataSource = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (row1, row2) => row1 !== row2});
    this.state = {
        dataSource: dataSource.cloneWithRows([]),
        refreshing: false
    };

    this._renderRow = this._renderRow.bind(this);
    this._getCoinData = this._getCoinData.bind(this);
}

componentWillMount() {
    this._getCoinData();
}

_getCoinData() {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        getCryptocurrencyData()
            .then(function (result) {
                const ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (row1, row2) => row1 !== row2});
                this.setState({
                    dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(result),
                    jsonData: result
                });
                resolve();
            }.bind(this))
    });
}


_renderRow(data) {
    return (
        <CoinCell
            coinName={data.name}
            coinPrice={data.price_gbp}
            coinPercentageChange={data.percent_change_24h}>
        </CoinCell>)
}

_renderHeader() {
    return (
        <Header />
    )
}

_onRefresh() {
    this.setState({refreshing: true});
    this._getCoinData()
        .then(() => {
            this.setState({refreshing: false});
        });
}


render() {
    return (
        <View>
            <ListView
                enableEmptySections
                refreshControl={
                    <RefreshControl
                        refreshing={this.state.refreshing}
                        onRefresh={this._onRefresh.bind(this)}
                    />
                }
                ref={'resultListView'}
                dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
                renderRow={this._renderRow}
                renderSeparator={(sectionId, rowId) => <View key={rowId} style={styles.separator}/>}
                renderHeader={() => this._renderHeader()}
            />
        </View>
    );
}
```

}

Comment: Include an example `result` being passed into `ds.cloneWithRows(result)`. It looks like you're expecting to use an array when populating your data source, but you're passing in raw JSON.

Comment: This is a shortened example of the `result: `https://pastebin.com/5FKgCTVV  and this is the `fetch()` method:    ```return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        fetch(url, {
            headers: {
                'Cache-Control': 'no-cache, no-store'
            }
        })
            .then((response) => resolve(response.json()))
            .catch((error) => {
                console.error(error);
            });
    })```

Answer (score 0):

used custom ScroolView is the best solution to rerender list data ti view.

```
dataSource = [ ['SectionAScene',strings.SectionA,false],
                  ['SectionBScene',strings.SectionB,false],
                  // ['SectionC1Scene',strings.SectionC1,false],
                  ['SectionD1Scene',strings.SectionD1,false],
                  // ['SectionEScene',strings.SectionE,false],
                  ['SectionFScene',strings.SectionF,false],
                  // ['SectionGScene',strings.SectionG,false],
                  ['SectionH1Scene',strings.SectionH,false],
                  ['SectionIScene',strings.SectionI,false],
                  ['SectionJScene',strings.SectionJ,false],
                  ['SectionKScene',strings.SectionK,false],
                  ['SectionLScene',strings.SectionL,false],
                  ['SectionMScene',strings.SectionM,false],
                  ['SectionNScene',strings.SectionN,false],
                  ['SectionOScene',strings.SectionO,false],
                  ['SectionPScene',strings.SectionP,false],
                  ['SectionQScene',strings.SectionQ,false],
                  ['SectionQ1Scene',strings.SectionQ1,false],
                  ['SectionRScene',strings.SectionR,false],
                  ['SectionSScene',strings.SectionS,false],
                  ];
```

render() {
    let data = this.state.dataSource;
    return (

```
{data != [] ?
     {this._renderHeader()}
              <ScrollView>
                 { data.map( (item,index) =>
                     <TouchableNativeFeedback onPress={this._onPressButton.bind(this,item)}>
                        <View style={item[2]? styles.itemSelected : styles.item}>
                          <Text>{item[1]}</Text>
                        <View style={{flex:1}} />
                        <Icon name={item[2]?"check":"chevron-right"} size={16} color="#444"/>
                        </View>
                      </TouchableNativeFeedback>
                     )}
                     </ScrollView>
                    :<View />}

    </View>
);
```

}